# How do I pass a sp_runtime::traits::Hash value into benchmark function

Tags: weight, benchmark

pallet code:

```rust
use sp_runtime::traits::{AccountIdConversion, Hash};
.......
.......
        pub do_something(...) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
         ......
        }

        pub fn say_hello(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            id: u32,
            hash: T::Hash,
            name: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
           ......
        }
```

benchmark code:

```rust
benchmarks! {
    do_something {
        let s in 1 .. 60u32;
        Template::<T>::say_hello(<T as frame_system::Config>::Origin::from(RawOrigin::Signed(bob)), s, hex!("d282f389399565f3671145f5916e51652b60eee8e5c759293a2f5771b8ddfd2e").into(), "hack".to_string().into());
        }
    }: _(RawOrigin::Root, s)


}
```

error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash: From<[u8; 32]>` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/template/src/benchmarking.rs:34:196
   |
34 | ...9293a2f5771b8ddfd2e").into(), "hack".to_string().into());
   |                          ^^^^ the trait `From<[u8; 32]>` is not implemented for `<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash>` for `[u8; 32]`
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Decode` trait in order to create a `frame_system::pallet::Config::Hash` from bytes:

```rust
let hash = T::Hash::decode(
    hex!("d282f389399565f3671145f5916e51652b60eee8e5c759293a2f5771b8ddfd2e").as_mut()
);
```

Comment: It felt close, but there was a problem.
```Template::<T>:: say_hello(<T as frame_system::Config>::Origin::from(RawOrigin::Signed(bob)), s, T::Hash::decode(hex!("d282f389399565f3671145f5916e51652b60eee8e5c759293a2f5771b8ddfd2e").as_ref()).unwrap(), "hack".to_string().into());
``` error msg -> ```.Hash::decode(hex!("d282f389399565f3671145f5916e51652b60eee8e5c759293a2f5771b8ddfd2e").as_ref()).unwrap(), "hack".to_string().into());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Should work now.

Comment: emmm, It's doesn't work.

47  |         let hash = T::Hash::decode(
    |                    --------------- required by a bound introduced by this call
48  |             hex!("d282f389399565f3671145f5916e51652b60eee8e5c759293a2f5771b8ddfd2e").as_mut()
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected an implementor of trait `Input`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Hash type` in benchmark. Please try to use this.

```rust
let hash = T::Hashing::hash_of(&1);
```